Is it safe let apple push services certificates and NotificationServiceExtension certificate expire if using APNs Auth Key?
I inherited maintainance for a messaging app. This app uses Notification service extension entitlement (which I never used before). App is not published on App Store, but delivered OTA, via website.
My colleague told me that in order to avoid certificate expiration issues, in the past started using APNs Auth Key on server.
Now, on developer profile page, I have two certificates close to expiration.

Both are of type "Apple push services"
First one, is named with my app bundleID (MyInstitution.AppName)
the second is named after Notification service extension entitlement (MyInstitution.AppName.NotificationServiceExtension)
in Key section on developer profile page, Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles -> Keys section, there is a key named MyInstitution NSE

MY QUESTION:

what do I should do with expiring certificates now that app is using APNs Auth Key ?
is Notification service extension entitlement working separately from APNs Auth Key?
in the end, what is needed to be renewed, and how?

some screenshot to be more clear

MyExpiration push certificates



The detail for my APNs Auth Key



You just need to renew push certificates and update provision profile once new certificates are created. This is very important step to update provision profile too.
With use of p8 file (APNs Auth Key), now you don't have to create p12/pem file for web developers every year.

Thank you for answering, but I'm not that expert with certificates and notifications, could you be more clear? In your opinion, in my situation, do I need to renew my certificates? Or using  APNs Auth Key cuts off the other two and they can die?

@biggreentree : Yes, you need to renew certificates as they are push certificates. Without that push won't work. P8 (APNs Auth Key) are just keys to connect them to those certificates... So every year just renew certificates... Because of p8 files we now don't need to create p12/pem files anymore...

sorry, I'm a bit confused here. Before of APNs Auth Key, there were required two different certificates for push notifications and the extension in order for notifications to work. Now, I still have those certificates, but they should be not required anymore, since app is using APNs Auth Key, right? Otherwise, if I still need to renew my two certificates for push notifications, I don't see the advantage in using APNs Auth Key.

now just you need to renew push certificate for the main app as shown in your screenshot (1 for development and 2nd for production)... for extension i believe you don't need push certificates....

"Before of APNs Auth Key, there were required two different certificates for push notifications and the extension in order for notifications to work." -> this is now replaced by p8. so you don't need to create new. one p8 for life time... just renew push certificates and we are done....

In apple forum they say this https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/758672, could you help me understand if this update allows me to do nothing? .  And if I need to update them, what is correct procedure? There is no button "renew" do I need to revoke them before they expire?
